# Access JSON data inside $http.post request from PHP MySql

Tags: php, angularjs

Is there a way accesing the json data from $http.post PHP mysql inside the function like this:

```
$scope.getAllNamesList = function() {
    $http.post("database/selectall_names.php", {user_id: $scope.selectedUserID})
    .then(function(response){
        $scope.names = response.data;

        if(response.data.user_city == "xxx")
            {
               $scope.selectedCity = response.data.user_city;
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: `.then(function(response){ console.log(response);...` what does that give you?

Comment: {data: Array(2), status: 200, headers: ƒ, config: {…}, statusText: "OK", …}

Comment: Your data property is an array, you can access it like: `response.data[0].user_city`, but you may want to iterate it using `response.data.forEach(function(element) { console.log(element. user_city)`, depends on what it is

Comment: response.data.forEach(function(element) { console.log(element. user_city) works perfect! @BrettGregson Nice thank you soo muuuch